# Chaining .htaccess rename rules - is the [L] directive necessary?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am converting my site to `ssl`. My htaccess currently has existing rules and I want to add a rule to rewrite all `http` requests to `https` (it is a shared server and I don't have access to the config files, so this is the only way).

The main two rules in question are the first (`http` to `https`) and the last (removing `www`).

What I am trying to wrap my head around is what will happen with chaining rules in this case and if I need the `[L]` directive with the `http` to `https` rename rule. I know `[L]` directive will cause an `.htaccess` loop and it would be more efficient to only make one pass through the rules if possible. If don't use the `[L]` directive (with the `http` to `https` rename rule), will the `www` renaming rule still work in one pass?

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}[L,R=301]

    #Rules for Versioned Static Files - remove timestamp
    RewriteRule ^(js|js-common|css|css-common|img|img-common)/(.+)\.([0-9])+\.(js|css|php|jpg|gif|png)(.*)$ $1/$2.$4$5 [L]

    #rename invalid file and directory requests
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?redirectroot=%{REQUEST_URI}

    #direct favicon requests to img directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/favicon.ico [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.ico [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/img/favicon.ico [R=301] 

    # remove www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `L` (`last`) flag is necessary for these *external (canonical) redirects*. "Chaining" doesn't really come into it - these are *external redirects* - you want processing to stop as soon as possible and send the redirect response back to the client. If you didn't include the `L` flag then processing will continue through the file and get rewritten to your front controller *before* the redirect occurs - which is certainly what you don't want to happen (as it will likely result in an external redirect to `/index.php?redirectroot=....`).

In fact, your directives are in the wrong order. As a general rule, *external redirects* should always come **before** *internal rewrites*. Your canonical redirects (www and HTTPS) should be together, near the top of your file, not at the end.

Also, your www to non-www redirect redirects to `http://`, which is in direct conflict with your HTTP to HTTPS redirect, which will create an unnecessary loop.

Your HTTP to HTTPS redirect is also invalid, as you are missing a space before the `RewriteRule` flags.

So, in summary:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#direct favicon requests to img directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/favicon.ico
RewriteRule favicon\.ico /img/favicon.ico [NC,L] 

#Rules for Versioned Static Files - remove timestamp
RewriteRule ^(js|js-common|css|css-common|img|img-common)/(.+)\.([0-9])+\.(js|css|php|jpg|gif|png)(.*)$ $1/$2.$4$5 [L]

#rename invalid file and directory requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?redirectroot=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

By including your www to non-www redirect before the HTTPS redirect and redirecting to the canonical `https://`, you avoid two potential redirects.

The `QSA` flag is not required, unless you are explicitly including a query string in the *substitution* and you wish to merge this with the query string on the request. (You are not including a query string on the www to non-www redirect, so this flag is not required.)

I've changed your *redirect* to the `/img/favicon.ico` to an *internal rewrite*. Not sure why you'd want to *redirect* here? I would also question the use of the `NC` flag here. You should only make the match case-insensitive if this is specifically required.

Also, I've removed the `NC` flag from the *negated* `RewriteCond` directive. Think about the logic.

> I know `[L]` directive will cause an `.htaccess` loop

In a `.htaccess` (directory) context, the `L` flag terminates the current pass through the `.htaccess` file. However, processing does indeed "loop", until the request passes through unchanged - except in the case of an external redirect (`R=3xx`), which gets triggered immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I hadn't realized the difference between an external and internal rewrite.The only logic I saw with making favicon an external rewrite was an attempt to tell google to stop hitting on the wrong path for the file. Would an `R=301` help them update their cache? Also, my version of the favicon renamed requests with an invalid directory in the request and your version will keep the invalid directory.

Comment: Maybe, in that case, a `R=301` would be necessary instead. However, this really should not be necessary - why is the wrong `favicon.ico` file being requested in the first place? And why is "Google" requesting this? It should be noted, however, that user-agents will tend to request `/favicon.ico` (in the document root) regardless of whether it is referenced in the HTML - there is nothing you can do about this unfortunately (which is why is it often preferable to simply rewrite `/favicon.ico` to the correct file). However, you seem to be targeting `favicon.ico` wherever it occurs in the URL?